# Cannot find module '../package.json'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, package.json

I've developed a WebApp and it works great at localhost, but on my server something goes wrong.
This is how I init my project

```
npm install 

npm run serve 

> shell-ui@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- /root/WebApp-2-0/shell-ui/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/WebApp-2-0/shell-ui/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service:4:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/root/WebApp-2-0/shell-ui/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service' ]
}

Node.js v19.9.0
```

On ls I 've got this

README.md        jsconfig.json  package-lock.json  public  vue.config.js
babel.config.js  node_modules   package.json       src

My OS is CentOS
Maybe you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the version of NCU:

if i run

> npm i npm-check-updates

If not solved, use this method:

Then I did `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` after clearing both the node_modules, package-lock.json. That finally fixed my issue.

Looks like npm install was overriding the legacy versions of dependencies with higher versions or skipping them altogether.